# xshell7 connect aws Amazon Linux 2023 failed

Tags: xshell

When I used xshell7 to connect to Amazon linux-2023, I reported an error and couldn't connect, but Amazon linux-2 was able to connect. Why is this? What should I do?

Comment: If you have SSH clients from several years ago, you might see an error when you connect to an instance. If the error tells you there's no matching host key type found, update your SSH host key to troubleshoot this issue.

Default disabling of ssh-rsa signatures

Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023) includes a default configuration that disables the legacy ssh-rsa host key algorithm and generates a reduced set of host keys. Clients must support the ssh-ed25519 or the ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key algorithm.

Comment: By default, AL2023 generates ed25519 and ECDSA host keys. Clients support either the ssh-ed25519 or the ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key algorithm. When you connect by SSH to an instance, you must use a client that supports a compatible algorithm, such as ssh-ed25519 or ecdsa-sha2-nistp256. If you need to use other key types, override the list of generated keys with a cloud-config fragment in user-data.

In the following example, cloud-config generates a rsa host key with the ecdsa and ed25519 keys.